# Retrieval of Jenkins environment variables while invoking ANT

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am invoking a windows batch command from Jenkins, after i get the latest version of my project from SVN. the windows batch command just performs certain file copying, after the all the files are retrieved from SVN and runs an ANT build. In the ANT build process, i am generating a JSP file where i have tried to capture the in the following fashion.

`%BUILD_TAG%-%BUILD_NUMBER%-%BUILD_ID%-%SVN_REVISION%`

Unfortunately none of this information is understood by the build process and it just writes `%BUILD_TAG%-%BUILD_NUMBER%-%BUILD_ID%-%SVN_REVISION%` into the file.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to capture these information into a file in the way i am trying to do? if not, could you direct me on how these information could be captured into a JSP file during the process that we are following?

Answer (score 1):

`BUILD_TAG`, `SVN_REVISION`, etc are all environment variables that are present during a Jenkins build, and to use them in Ant, you would use them as any other environment variable from Ant

First, add a line:
`<property environment="env"/>`
Then you can reference any environment variable with this prefix, like:
`${env.VAR_NAME}`

So in your case, you'd do:

`${env.BUILD_TAG}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${env.BUILD_ID}-${env.SVN_REVISION}`